# Can I do "dotnet watch" for Asp.Net Core web application targeting "dotnet framework 4.6.1"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-4.6.1

Looks like "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" is compatible with only application targeting framework (.Net Core).

I have a asp.net core web application (web api) that target framework (dotnet 4.6.1), Is there any way that I can watch the code change?

Regards,